# binary search in python, outputting the value checked

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a project which required me to output each value checked during the binarysearch. 
For example, if the input is `3,1,5` and `1`, it will output 3 then 1. If it is found in the list, it will print yes, otherwise print no. 
Another example is if the user input `3,1,5` and `6`, it will output `3` then `5` and `No`
Here is what I have got now.

```
def BinSearch (item,candidates):

    if len(candidates)>0:
        mid = len(candidates)//2

        if item == candidates[mid]:
            print (item)
        if item < candidates[mid]:
            print (candidates[mid])       
            BinSearch([item,candidates[:mid-1]])
        else:
            print (candidates[mid])
            BinSearch(item,candidates[mid+1:])


haystack = []
for item in input().split(','):
    haystack.append(int(item))
haystack.sort()

needles = []
for item in input().split(','):
    needles.append(int(item))


for needle in needles:
    BinSearch(needle,haystack)
```

from running the above code, 
For the input `3,1,5` and `1`, my code only output `3` `Yes` but not `3` `1` `Yes`

Comment: Sooo, what's the problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, i have just edited my question, thanks.

Comment: You should check at which line your stacktrace is raised, it will give the answer you need...

Answer (score 2):

`BinSearch([item,candidates[:mid-1]])` should be `BinSearch(item,candidates[:mid-1])`

By the way, you should really pay attention the stack trace you get when an error occurs. It would have told you exactly in which line of code the problem occurs and form there you should have been able to figure out that you've passed the parameters incorrectly

Comment: I am too careless.. sorry, i will improve that! Btw it still cant get the correct results as i mentioned. For the input `3,1,5` and `1`, my code only output `3` `Yes` but not `3` `1` `Yes`

Comment: Let's see, on the first pass `mid==1` and `candidates[mid]==3`. The first nested 'if' statement is false, the second one is true. So `3` is printed.

On the second pass you do `BinSearch(1,candidates[:0])` which is the same as `BinSearch(1,[])` i.e. `len(candidates)>0` is false so nothing further happens.

Put some print statements in your code or use a debugger so that you can see what is happening!